# Negative numbers in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm currently struggling with how to use negative numbers in ARM assembly. Let's say I have a simple code like this:

```
MOV R0, #0
SUB R0, R0, #1
SWI 4
```

`R0` will obviously store the value `0xFFFFFFFF`, but `SWI` doesn't seem to treat it as a signed integer and so the number that gets displayed is 4294967295. How can I print out -1?

Comment: Why use SWI?  What environment are you running on/in that you are communicating with with SWI?

Comment: Have to agree with dwelch. Why use SWI? If you want it to be treated as a signed integer, send it to a function expecting to receive a signed integer.

Comment: to load -1 to R0 use `MVN R0, #0` instead of 2 instructions like that

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, `SWI 4` invokes some number displaying routine in the OS or whatever execution environment there is. If there's an appropriate `SWI some other number` for displaying signed integers, use that. You should really mention your OS.

If there's no signed counterpart to `SWI 4`, compute the absolute value of the negative number (e.g. subtract it from 0) and then display separately the minus sign and the absolute value. Negative values have the most significant bit set to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use Linux, and have never heard of any `SWI` for displaying signed integers.